# Require explanation for the output

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j = 7, i = 4;
    j = j || ++i && printf("you can");
    printf("%d %d",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
4 1

[Code Link][1]

1. The precedence of prefix operator is higher than logical operators. 
   2.Logical `&&` has higher precedence than logical `||`.
2. In Logical AND(`&&`) if first operand evaluates to false than second will not be evaluated and In Logical OR(`||)` if first operand evaluates to `true`, then second will not be evaluated.
3. The complete expression is evaluating to `true`, therefore j is 1 .

Doubts:

1. Why the first rule is not followed here? Shouldn't it be correct?

   ```
   j=(j||((++i) &&printf("you can")));
   ```

Therefore value of `i` becomes 5, in the `printf` statement.

Why are the general precedence rules are violated here? Associativity comes into action when precedence of two operators is same. Shouldn't the compiler first see whether to evaluate `||` or `&&`?

If `||` is evaluated first, which shouldn't be as per my knowledge, then result is correct.  However, if it is not evaluated first, then you can51 should be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression:

```
j = j || ++i && printf("you can");
```

There's a sequence point after the `||` and it is evaluated from left to right. Since j is non-zero, the rest of the expression is not evaluated. Hence, `j || (....)` becomes true which is 1. Since is `++i` is not evaluated i remains 4. Hence, the output is `4, 1`.

From the C standard:

> **Annex C**
>
> — The end of the ﬁrst operand of the following operators: logical AND
>   && (6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14); conditional ? (6.5.15); comma ,
>   (6.5.17).

If you `j` was zero then `++i && printf("you can")` would have been evaluated and `i` would become 5 and `you can` will also be printed. You are correct about the precedence of ++ being greater than ||, but since there's a sequence point, `j||` is evalauted first.

Comment: The logical OR operator has its two operands as j and ++i , it is fine if you say ++i is not evaluated but why not printf? isn't it that printf is an operand of AND operator here.?

Comment: Because && has higher precedence, it's treated as if: `j||(++i &&printf("you can"))`. Since there's an intervening sequence point, `j||` is evaluated first. Hence the 2nd part is not evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

`j || ++i && printf("you can")` evaluates to true, which is represented by `1`.  Because it is an OR, and because j is non-zero, only the left hand of the OR is evaluated, so the `++i` and the `printf` aren't evaluated.  Thus `j` is 1 and `i` stays at 4.

Of course, real code should never every do anything like that.  You should always write code in ways that the order of operations is obvious, and you should almost never have code with side effects in OR statements.

Comment: The logical OR operator has its two operands as j and ++i , it is fine if you say ++i is not evaluated but why not printf?

Comment: @tapasweni: No, the second operand of `||` is the *expression* `++i && printf("you can")`.  The expression is parsed as `j || (++i && printf("you can"))`.  Since `j` evaluates to non-zero, *everything* after the `||` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here:

```
j = j || ++i && printf("you can");
```

Is a logic expression (there's no math happening). Let's break it down:

```
++i                // as a mathematical expression this is i=i+1 (5 in your case)
printf("you can"); // printf returns the number of chars written, (7)
```

So you'd expect this to be:

```
j = 7 || 5 && 7;
```

The output of the above expression is simply 1. So even if this executed you should see `j=1`. So why don't you see the `printf()` output?
The reason to that is that whole expression **didn't run**. It doesn't have to. Consider:

```
result = TRUE || (anything else);
```

Anything that's "true" or'd with anything else will always return true. The compiler knows this and once it sees `7 ||` it equates that to `true ||` and says "I know enough, set j to true and move on".

This is why the expression doesn't increment i and why it doesn't print "you can".
Now if you were to flip the expression:

```
j = ++i && printf("you can") || j;
```

The logic stays the same but the compiler doesn't see the || until it's evaluated everything else, so i will be incremented and the printf will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this program two ways:

```
j = j || ++i && printf("you can");
```

then, like this:

```
j = j || (++i && printf("you can"));
```

The output for both was `4 1`. Before I ran them, I expected to get the exact same result from both due to the left to right associativity of logical or. The entire expression is gonna be evaluated from left to right regardless. The role of the parentheses is to ensure that an expression is evaluated as one expression, and doesn't necessarily mean that it will be the first expression to be evaluated. If you want more evidence of this, try something simple:

```
j = 1 || (++i);
```

Even though `(++i)` is in parenthesis, it is never evaluated. Again, because of left to right associativity.